# Highlight selected Item with a BackgroundColor in MasterDetail Flow using RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, master-detail

I'm doing a Mobile App for **Tablets** and I have added a **Master/Detail Flow** using the Android Studio steps. I have noticed that when you select an item, **the item is not highlighted**, the user can't figure out what item he touched.

I did a research and I have found nothing that works for me. All the suggestions are for ListView and **my case use a RecyclerView**.

I tried at least changing the background color inside of the onClick method and it works but, the color don't go away when you touch another item.

**ProductListActivity:**

```
public class ProductListActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    /**
     * Whether or not the activity is in two-pane mode, i.e. running on a tablet
     * device.
     */
    private boolean mTwoPane;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_product_list);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        toolbar.setTitle(getTitle());

        if (findViewById(R.id.product_detail_container) != null) {
            // The detail container view will be present only in the
            // large-screen layouts (res/values-w900dp).
            // If this view is present, then the
            // activity should be in two-pane mode.
            mTwoPane = true;
        }

        View recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.product_list);
        assert recyclerView != null;
        setupRecyclerView((RecyclerView) recyclerView);
    }

    private void setupRecyclerView(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView) {
        recyclerView.setAdapter(new SimpleItemRecyclerViewAdapter(this, DummyContent.ITEMS, mTwoPane));
        recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(this, DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL));
    }

    public static class SimpleItemRecyclerViewAdapter
            extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SimpleItemRecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder> {

        private final ProductListActivity mParentActivity;
        private final List<DummyContent.DummyItem> mValues;
        private final boolean mTwoPane;
        private final View.OnClickListener mOnClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                DummyContent.DummyItem item = (DummyContent.DummyItem) view.getTag();
                if (mTwoPane) {
                    Bundle arguments = new Bundle();
                    arguments.putString(ProductDetailFragment.ARG_ITEM_ID, item.id);
                    ProductDetailFragment fragment = new ProductDetailFragment();
                    fragment.setArguments(arguments);
                    mParentActivity.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                            .replace(R.id.product_detail_container, fragment)
                            .commit();

                    // Custom color for the selected item
                    view.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                } else {
                    Context context = view.getContext();
                    Intent intent = new Intent(context, ProductDetailActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra(ProductDetailFragment.ARG_ITEM_ID, item.id);

                    context.startActivity(intent);
                }
            }
        };

        SimpleItemRecyclerViewAdapter(ProductListActivity parent,
                                      List<DummyContent.DummyItem> items,
                                      boolean twoPane) {
            mValues = items;
            mParentActivity = parent;
            mTwoPane = twoPane;
        }

        @Override
        public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.product_list_content, parent, false);
            return new ViewHolder(view);
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, int position) {
            holder.mIdView.setText(mValues.get(position).id);
            holder.mContentView.setText(mValues.get(position).content);

            holder.itemView.setTag(mValues.get(position));
            holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(mOnClickListener);
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return mValues.size();
        }

        class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
            final TextView mIdView;
            final TextView mContentView;

            ViewHolder(View view) {
                super(view);
                mIdView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.id_text);
                mContentView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.content);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**product_list.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:background="@drawable/border_all"
    android:divider="?android:attr/dividerHorizontal"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:showDividers="middle"
    tools:context=".activities.Inventory.ProductListActivity">

    <!--
    This layout is a two-pane layout for the Products
    master/detail flow.

    -->

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/product_list"
        android:name="com.applab.nestlenido.activities.Inventory.ProductListFragment"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/item_width"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layoutManager="LinearLayoutManager"
        tools:context="com.applab.nestlenido.activities.Inventory.ProductListActivity"
        tools:listitem="@layout/product_list_content" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/product_detail_container"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="3" />

</LinearLayout>
```

My goal is to **change the background color of the selected item**. If you touch another item, the previous item should be with no background and the new item should have now the background (the normal behavior).

Comment: You question is similar to this question, please check my answer there https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56197184/grouping-switches-inside-recyclerview

Comment: @Ezaldeensahb Hi, thanks for trying to help me. That link didn't help me much. I tried to do it but didn't work for me. I don't know if the MasterDetail Flow has its own way to do this.