# Grouping Switches inside RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, grouping

I am currently facing difficulty trying to group the switches inside  recylerView. I have attached my code below and a snapshot of the screen.
As you can see, I can now toogle any switch but at a given point in time , I want only one switch to be toggled on.

Item_list.xml :-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
android:clickable="true"
android:focusable="true"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/row_padding_vertical"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/row_padding_vertical">


<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="87dp"
android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
card_view:cardCornerRadius="8dp">

<LinearLayout
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="95dp"
 android:background="#20b2aa"
 android:orientation="vertical">

 <LinearLayout
 android:layout_width="182dp"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
 android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
 android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
 android:orientation="horizontal">

 <TextView
 android:id="@+id/name"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:textColor="#ffff"
 android:textSize="32dp" />


 </LinearLayout>

 <Switch

 android:id="@+id/value"
 android:layout_width="59dp"
 android:layout_height="3dp"
 android:layout_marginLeft="190dp"
 android:layout_marginTop="-35dp"
 android:layout_marginBottom="100dp"
 android:scaleX="1.1"
 android:scaleY="1.1"
 android:theme="@style/SwitchTheme" />

 </LinearLayout>
 </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

 </LinearLayout>
 </RelativeLayout>
```

---

ItemAdapter:-

```
package com.example.loginpage;

import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Switch;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.List;

public class ItemAdapter extends 
RecyclerView.Adapter<ItemAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

private int cn=0;
private List<Item> itemList;

public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
public TextView name;
public Switch value;

public MyViewHolder(View view) {
super(view)   
name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name);
value = (Switch) view.findViewById(R.id.value);
}
}

public ItemAdapter(List<Item> itemList) {
this.itemList = itemList;
}


@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int 
viewType) {
View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
.inflate(R.layout.item_list, parent, false);

return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
Item item = itemList.get(position);
holder.name.setText(item.getName());
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
return itemList.size();
}

}
```

---

My current interface looks like this....
https://www.pastepic.xyz/image/8z5Eh

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you set a Click listener on all value  switches and disable all switches when any switch clicked.

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
Item item = itemList.get(position);
 holder.name.setText(item.getName());
 holder.value.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        for (Item x: itemList){
          //  x.Selected=false; 
          // here you make all of your switches to false
        }
        //itm.Selected = true;
        // here you make the current switch to on or true
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
});
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {

    Item item = itemList.get(position);

    holder.name.setText(item.getName());
    holder.value.setChecked(item.isValueChecked());

    holder.value.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener(
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
        boolean isChecked) {

            for(Item i: itemList){
                i.setValueChecked(false);
            }

            if(buttonView.isChecked()){
                itemList.get(position).setValueChecked(true);
                holder.value.setChecked(true);
            }

            notifyDataSetChanged();

    }

    });
}
```

**Try this solution, this should work...**

**Checked Change Listener** is set on the switch if any switch is turned ON then all the **values** of the **itemList** is made false and current **value** is made True and switch is set ON, finally, **notifyDataSetChanged()** is called.

If any switch is turned OFF then all the **values** in the **itemList** are made False and **notifyDataSetChanged()** is called so that the switch state gets updated.

> ```
>   holder.value.setChecked(item.isValueChecked());
> ```

This updates the switch state based on the values stored in the **itemList**.